# Managed Property not appearing in webpart

Tags: web-part, modern-experience, managed-property, crawled-property

I have created a list in a SharePoint Communication site. The list was populated and has several columns to describe the information. The columns appear as crawled properties (ows_XXXXX). What I did was go into Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Search Schema and mapped the crawled properties to RefinableStringXX. I have reindexed the site as well as reindexed the list. However, when I use SPfx Modern Search Webpart, I cannot see the RefinableStrings. If I use a standard webpart, I cannot see them either. I have also manually typed the name of the RefinableString into the webpart and nothing shows up. It's been over a week since I have done the reindexing. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What is the name of your List column?

Comment: @MartinMuldoon I have a few columns in the list. Some of the names are GeoFocus, BUPoC, BUPoC1, etc. Some of the columns have similar names to columns in a Document library, but they are different and show up as different crawled properties. For example, BUPoC1 in the list and ProjectBUPoC1 in the Document column